# Array in shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to store the output of the `diff` command into an array and to find the length of the array using a Bash script. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```bsh
arr=( $(diff -w file1 file2 | grep '<' | awk '{print $10}') )

arr=( $(diff -w file1 file2 | grep '>' | awk '{print $10}') )

echo "$arr"
echo "number of files : ${#arr[@]}"
```

Comment: "didn't work" is a useless problem description. What **did** happen, and how did that differ from what you expected to happen?

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, you don't need an array at all. The length of the array would be equal to the number of words. There's a command for that: `wc` ("word count").

However, looking at these commands:

> ```
> arr=( $(diff -w file1 file2 | grep '<' | awk '{print $10}') )
> arr=( $(diff -w file1 file2 | grep '>' | awk '{print $10}') )
> echo "number of files : ${#arr[@]}"
> ```

My guess is that what you really want is: extract column 10 from lines that start with `<` or `>`:

```
files=($(diff -w file1 file2 | awk '/^[<>]/ {print $10}') )
```

Even better using `readarray` / `mapfile` to avoid sub-shells (thanks [@kos](https://askubuntu.com/users/380067/kos) for the tip):

```
readarray files < <(diff -w file1 file2 | awk '/^[<>]/ {print $10}')
```

Comment: @kos cool, I hope to see you there soon